# Android app error: net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusSlaveException: Error Code = 2

Tags: java, android, modbus

i'm using the JAMOD with android to read data from modbus.
i have a slave and a master class.(slave is running in netbeans)

triing to connect with the android apk and got the error message which is in the title.
Can you help me why or how to correct my app?

```
import net.wimpi.modbus.Modbus;
    import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusCoupler;
    import net.wimpi.modbus.net.ModbusTCPListener;
    import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.*;


public class Modbus_slave_server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ModbusTCPListener listener = null;
        SimpleProcessImage spi = new SimpleProcessImage();
        int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;

        if (Modbus.debug) {
            System.out.println("jModbus Modbus TCP Slave");
        }
        if (args != null && args.length >= 1) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        try {

            //2. Prepare a process image
            spi = new SimpleProcessImage();
            spi.addInputRegister(new SimpleInputRegister(635)); //érték beállítás

            //3. Set the image on the coupler
            ModbusCoupler.getReference().setProcessImage(spi);
            ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(false);
            ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1);



            //3. create a listener with 3 threads in pool
            if (Modbus.debug) {
                System.out.println("Listening...");
            }

            listener = new ModbusTCPListener(1);
            listener.setPort(port);
            listener.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//main
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using liblary for modbus in C#(NModbus) and SlaveException means thean your slave device return error: http://www.simplymodbus.ca/exceptions.htm 
Error code number 2 means that:

> The data address received in the query is not an allowable address for
>   the slave. More specifically, the combination of reference number and
>   transfer length is invalid. For a controller with 100 registers, a
>   request with offset 96 and length 4 would succeed, a request with
>   offset 96 and length 5 will generate exception 02.

http://www.kepware.com/Support_Center/SupportDocuments/KTAN90006_Modbus_Exception_Codes.pdf